# Why is check_linux_raid missing from nagios plugins in 13.04?

Tags: package-management, 13.04, nagios3

After upgrading to 13.04 my Nagios monitoring started to notify me of a problem with my raid setup (mdadm raid). After some investigation it seems the check_linux_raid plugin is not included anymore in any of the nagios plugins packages. At least as far as I could see.

Is this intentional? If yes, which plugin am I supposed to use for checking a linux software raid?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is intentional. See the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/n/nagios-plugins/nagios-plugins_1.4.16-1ubuntu3/changelog):

```
nagios-plugins (1.4.15-6) unstable; urgency=low

[...]
  * Removed check_bgpstate and check_linux_raid from package
[...]
```

Looks like `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_raid` in the [nagios-plugins-contrib [image: Install nagios-plugins-contrib]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nagios-plugins-contrib) package does the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin normally is in /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_linux_raid if you run it, should return with your md status. Is that file missing? If so do you have nagios-plugins package installed? If none of the above helps hack the plugin in manually http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/Linux-Software-Raid-Plugin-for-32-2Dbit-and-64-2Dbit-systems/details